# Rails-4.2 delete a 'through' assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, model-associations

What is the simplest syntax to destroy/break an association where the values for the indexes to the two principal tables is known?

```
User has_many roles through clearances
Role has_many users through clearances

Clearance[.id, .user_id, .role_id]
Role[.id, .rolename]
User[.id, .username]

username == 'auser'
rolename == 'arole'
```

I wish to delete the clearance row that connects these two values but do not touch either primary table.

2015-07-08
The solution that works for me is:

```
  mu = User.find_by!( :username => uname )
  mr = Role.find_by!( :rolename => rname )
  rc = mu.authorisations.find_by( :role_id => mr.id )
  rc.delete if rc
```

The suggestions by @Hristo below cause this error:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: authorisations.username: SELECT "authorisations".* FROM "authorisations" WHERE "authorisations"."username" = 'xtra_user' AND "authorisations"."rolename" = 'test_role' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

> N.B. as this is a project under active development the term clearance
>   was replaced by authorisation and the models renamed and edited
>   accordingly.

As pointed out in the original question the join table has only the referenced id values of the belongs_to models.

Comment: Did I answer your question? :)

Comment: Thank you. You probably have but I have not had the opportunity to prove it.  For some reason I did not receive an email for your answer, only for your follow up.  I necessarily moved on with a work-around. I will mark the Q as answered as soon as I show myself that this formulation does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clearance.where(age: "auser", rolename: "arole").destroy_all
```

or

```
Clearance.destroy_all(age: "auser", rolename: "arole")
```

Should be able to do it and are short enough.

Comment: No, this does not work.  The work-around that I used was this: